# Android listview clicked item is not completly hichlighted

Tags: android, listview, highlight

Why when I click on items, the item is not completly highlightet?

**xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <SearchView
     android:id="@+id/search_lists_layout_search"
     android:layout_width="250dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>     
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/search_lists_layout_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can see picture here http://oi61.tinypic.com/2niqn9i.jpg

**Adapter**

```
final ListView listview=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_lists_layout_listview);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,moshtarinames);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: post your adpter code

Comment: and layout for item of the listview

Comment: I think something wrog in <ListView .... /> ,no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout raw must have its `android:layout_width` set to `match_parent` if you want it to take the whole width of the ListView

Comment: so i can use 'android:layout_width' set to 'wrap_content' in my listview attribs ,yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/search_lists_layout_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```